# hello I am getting an error that shows up in discord modal it tells Something went wrong. try again discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello I made a mail command which would take message from modal and send it to a mentioned user but it gives this error in modal window and does not log anything in console
[image: here is the image]

```
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');
const { Modal, TextInputComponent, showModal } = require('discord-modals')
const { Formatters } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args, prefix) => {
  let member = message.mentions.members.first();
  if(!message.content.includes(member)) {
    embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RED')
    .setTitle('Whome shd I send this mail to bruh')
    .setDescription('Please mention the user whome you want to deliver the message')
    await message.reply({embeds:[embed]})
  }
  else {
    msg = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle('its time to type your message to your friend')
    .setDescription('Please type your subject and message as you do while composing a normal mail using gmail just click the button and fill the subject and the message in their respective fields')

    const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
    new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('compose')
                    .setLabel('Fill up info and compose')
                    .setEmoji('')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
      );
    const msg = await message.reply({embeds:[msg],components: [row]});

    //defining intput text fields
    let textinput = new TextInputComponent()
    .setCustomId('textinput-customid')
    .setLabel('Subject')
    .setStyle('SHORT')
    .setMinLength('1')
    .setMaxLength('200')
    .setPlaceholder('type your Subject here it can be anything in less than 200 words')
    .setRequired(true)

    let textinputl = new TextInputComponent()
    .setCustomId('textinput-customidl')
    .setLabel('Message')
    .setStyle('LONG')
    .setMinLength('1')
    .setMaxLength('4000')
    .setPlaceholder('type your message here it can be anything in less than 4000 words')
    .setRequired(true)
    //main modal

    const modal = new Modal() // We create a Modal
    .setCustomId('modal-customid')
    .setTitle('Compose a mail')
    .addComponents([ textinput, textinputl ])


    Client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
      if(interaction.isButton) {
        if(interaction.customId === 'compose'){
          showModal(modal, {
            client: Client,
            interaction: interaction
          })
        }
      }
    })


    Client.on('modalSubmit', async (modal) => {
      if(modal.customId === 'modal-customid'){
        const subjectresponse = modal.getTextInputValue('textinput-customid')
        const messageresponse = modal.getTextInputValue('textinput-customidl')
        modal.followUp({ content: 'Done message delivered.' + Formatters.codeBlock('markdown', firstResponse), ephemeral: true })
        
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('You have a new mail')
        .setDescription(`${message.author.username} has sent you an email`)
        .addField('Subject:', `${subjectresponse}`, false)
        .addField('Message:', `${messageresponse}`, false)
        await message.reply({embeds:[embed]});
      }
    })
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'mail',
    aliases: []
}
```

this is the code please check it out and tell what is the error
on the git error page of this people were asking about it but I dint understand that

Comment: Looks like you are missing `modal.deferReply()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to make a lot of code changes, here is what the final result was below, basically the issue was that there were a lot of variances in the code and how the code was handled. Needed to add checks to the code to help it move along. Added the member id to the embed to help the bot get that id when it needed it later.

command.js file

```js
const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!mentionedMember || mentionedMember.user.bot) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RED')
        .setTitle('Whom should I send this mail to bruh')
        .setDescription('Please mention the user whom you want to deliver the message, no bots');
    message.reply({
        embeds: [embed],
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        message.delete();
    }, 100);
} else {
    const rickrollmsg = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('GREEN')
        .setTitle('its time to type your message to your friend')
        .setDescription('Please type your subject and message as you do while composing a normal mail using gmail just click the button and fill the subject and the message in their respective fields')
        .setFooter({
            text: mentionedMember.id,
        });

    const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('compose')
        .setLabel('Fill up info and compose')
        .setEmoji('')
        .setStyle('SECONDARY'),
    );
    message.reply({
        embeds: [rickrollmsg],
        components: [row],
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        message.delete();
    }, 100);
}
```

interactionCreate button code

```js
const textinput = new TextInputComponent()
    .setCustomId('rickmail-subject')
    .setLabel('Subject')
    .setStyle('SHORT')
    .setMinLength('1')
    .setMaxLength('200')
    .setPlaceholder('type your Subject here it can be anything in less than 200 words')
    .setRequired(true);

const textinputl = new TextInputComponent()
    .setCustomId('rickmail-message')
    .setLabel('Message')
    .setStyle('LONG')
    .setMinLength('1')
    .setMaxLength('4000')
    .setPlaceholder('type your message here it can be anything in less than 4000 words')
    .setRequired(true);

const modal = new Modal()
    .setCustomId('rickmail')
    .setTitle('Compose a rickmail')
    .addComponents([textinput, textinputl]);

showModal(modal, {
    client: client,
    interaction: inter,
});
```

modalSubmit listener

```js
const member = modal.guild.members.cache.get(modal.message.embeds[0].footer.text);
const subject = modal.getTextInputValue('rickmail-subject');
const message = modal.getTextInputValue('rickmail-message');

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle(`${subject}`)
    .setDescription(`${message}`)
    .setImage('https://www.icegif.com/wp-content/uploads/rick-roll-icegif-5.gif')
    .setFooter({
        text: `Message Received ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`,
    });
modal.message.delete();
member.send({
    embeds: [embed],
});
return modal.followUp({
    content: 'Rickmail sent',
    ephemeral: true,
});
```

Comment: bro yesterday after fix it worked and today in the morning my bot was offline I changed my token and used the error it sent the message and threw an error telling something about response.delete() then now I saw it is not turning on the bot I mean it shows everything correctly no error but still it does not bring my bot online

Comment: nope still dint work it does not log any eror

Comment: and the bot doesent come up online

Comment: Hmm so what about running it on hereku or is there any way for keeping vs code 24/7 online without keeping pc turned on

Comment: hmm my friend gave a google cloud account what about that

Comment: it is also a server

Comment: I am testing what we have got in that google cloud account

Comment: sorry for trouble but this is the last ig coz everything is done  

**response.delete()
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete')
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/js-try3/events/modalSubmit.js:26:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
** sows this error

Comment: K lemme try it and tell

Comment: nope it dint still shows an error on sending it sends the message to the mentioned user but then throws this error and one more error it does not send the message with a button to fill a message in the modal if you mention a member who has a nickname  on the server basically does not work for mentioning nickname people can we try using try statement for response.delete