# Problems with Discord.js modal: 'Something went wrong! Try again!'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
   async function createTicketModal(interaction, ticketType) {
      if (interaction.deferred || interaction.replied) {
        // Interaction has already been replied to or deferred
        return;
      }
    
      const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('ticketModal')
        .setTitle(`${ticketType} - Ticket`);
    
      const questionModal = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId('questionModal')
        .setLabel('Please describe your problem.')
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);
    
      const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(questionModal);
    
      modal.addComponents(firstActionRow);
    
      const modalMessage = await interaction.showModal(modal);
    
      try {
        const modalResponse = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
          filter: (i) =>
            i.customId === "ticketModal" &&
            i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
          time: 60000,
        });
    
        if (modalResponse.isMessageComponent()) {
          const description = modalResponse.values[0];
    
          const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(`${interaction.user.username}-ticket`, {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.guild.id,
                deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
              },
              {
                id: interaction.user.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'ATTACH_FILES'],
              },
            ],
          });
    
          if (!channel.isText()) {
            await modalMessage.editReply({
              content: `Failed to create a text channel for your ${ticketType} ticket.`,
              embeds: [],
              components: [],
            });
            return;
          }
    
          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`${ticketType} Ticket`)
            .setDescription(`Problem Description: ${description}`)
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .build();
    
          await channel.send(`${interaction.user}`, { embeds: [embed] });
    
          // Close the modal by updating the interaction with an empty array of components
          await modalMessage.editReply({ components: [] });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await modalMessage.editReply({
          content: `An error occurred while creating your ${ticketType} ticket. Please try again later.`,
          embeds: [],
          components: [],
        });
      }
    }
```

All begins when you send the command (`/ticket`) to a channel. Right after the bot sends an embed message with 4 buttons. When I click a button on the first embed it just sends a modal asking 'Please describe your problem.' But the problem is, when I submit it, the modal says:

[image: 1]

### Note

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944561/hello-i-am-getting-an-error-that-shows-up-in-discord-modal-it-tells-something-we) does not seem to be a duplicate because it doesn't suit/solve my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you never respond to the form submission. I don't think `modalResponse.isMessageComponent()` is what you need as the response is not a `MessageComponent` but a `ModalSubmit`. You'll need to use `modalResponse.isModalSubmit()` instead.

Also, there are no values with modal submit, so `modalResponse.values` won't work. You should use `modalResponse.fields`. To get the description, you can use `modalResponse.fields.getTextInputValue('questionModal')`.

There are some other issues with your code if you're using discord.js v14. E.g. you should use `type: ChannelType.GuildText` instead of `type: 'text'` when you create a channel. Also, the [channel name should be included in the `options` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75820623/6126373). `permissionOverwrites` should also use enums, like `PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel` instead of `"VIEW_CHANNEL"`, etc.

Another thing is that `interaction.showModal` returns void ([as I mentioned earlier)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75940058/6126373), so you can't use `modalMessage.editReply`. You could use `modalResponse.reply` instead.

Although I haven't checked it, something like this should work:

```js
const modal = new ModalBuilder()
  .setCustomId('ticketModal')
  .setTitle(`${ticketType} - Ticket`);

const questionModal = new TextInputBuilder()
  .setCustomId('questionModal')
  .setLabel('Please describe your problem.')
  .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);

const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(questionModal);

modal.addComponents(firstActionRow);

await interaction.showModal(modal);

try {
  const modalResponse = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
    filter: (i) =>
      i.customId === 'ticketModal' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
    time: 60000,
  });

  if (modalResponse.isModalSubmit()) {
    const description = modalResponse.fields.getTextInputValue('questionModal');

    const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
      name: `${interaction.user.username}-ticket`,
      type: ChannelType.GuildText,
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: interaction.guild.id,
          deny: PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel,
        },
        {
          id: interaction.user.id,
          allow: [
            PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel,
            PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages,
            PermissionFlagsBits.AttachFiles,
          ],
        },
      ],
    });

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(`${ticketType} Ticket`)
      .setDescription(`Problem Description: ${description}`)
      .setColor('#0099ff');

    await channel.send(`${interaction.user}`, { embeds: [embed] });

    await modalResponse.reply({
      content: `Support channel successfully created. Head over to ${channel}`,
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  await interaction.reply({
    content: `An error occurred while creating your ${ticketType} ticket. Please try again later.`,
    embeds: [],
    components: [],
  });
}
```